# Data Structure to get all elements at certain position

Tags: java, memory-management, data-structures, hash

I have a square `Grid` with a certain height and width. It contains members of the class `Item`. Every `Item` has a certain `Position`. I'd like to be able to get all the items at a certain position in constant time, and I'd like to be able to place an item on the grid in amortized constant time.

What (Java) structure can do this while using an amount of memory proportional to the amount of used positions (positions with at least 1 item on it)?

Comment: Does your `Grid` has a fixed size or is it dynamically growing?

Comment: It has a fixed size. `Position` is a class of position with an x and an y value (both of type `long`). I forgot to mention that the grid should use memory proportional to its positions containing items (positions in use), not proportional to it's size.

Answer (score 1):

If your Grid has a fixed size I would use an array.

```
Item[][] itemArray = new Item[3][3];
itemArray[0][0] = new Item();
System.out.println(itemArray[0][0]);
```

I would wrap that into the class `Grid`

```
public final class Grid {

    private Item[][] grid;

    public Grid(int width, int height) {
        grid = new Item[width][height];
    }

    public void setItemAt(Position position, Item item) {
        int x = position.getX();
        int y = position.getY();

        grid[x][y] = item;
    }

    public Item getItemAt(Position position) {
        int x = position.getX();
        int y = position.getY();

        return grid[x][y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user above is right that internally you can use an array. Of course it should be of type `List<Item>[][]`. No matter if you use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, adding will be amortized constant time. Though I would suggest going for a `LinkedList`, as your `Grid` is likely to be sparsely populated (`ArrayList` always starts with a couple of spaces already allocated).

If the `Grid` needs to be able to grow, just use the same trick `ArrayList` uses: keep track of current width/height, and if you need more just multiply available space by a suitable value (for a 2D array, doubling might be a bit much, but it depends on the type of growth that is possible).